# WP_Query not working when using tax_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do a `WP_Query` in a custom page template to retrieve posts that are in the category with id 4003 **AND** either in category with ID `$category_id` **OR** have the tag with slug `$category_slug`.
I'm using this code:

```
<?php $args3 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 4003,
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category_slug
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_id
            )
        )
    ),
    );
    $query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
?>
```

It seems that the problem is the `tag` query, because posts with both categories 4003 and `$category_id` are correctly retrieved. I *know* that there are posts with category 4003 and tag `$category_slug` but I cannot retrieve them.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to double check your arrays in the tax_query - you are asking for `field => 'ID',` instead of `field => 'term_id',`. Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but it is a good idea to stick to the standard :)

Comment: See this solution https://wpquestions.com/Multiple_relationship_for_multiple_tax_query_in_WP_Query/8326

Comment: Thanks @Frits :) I've edited my code (although it was not the cause of the problem)